# Link to a nested category

Tags: matrix, categories, nested

I'm using a matrix field to allow the author to add products they can link to category pages, but my code:

```
{% for block in entry.transformerProductNavigation %}
 <a href="{{ block.transformer.one.url }}">{{ block.transformer.one.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

outputs the parent category, can I somehow display the nested category – as you would if it was an entry field and nested entries?

Comment: With an entry field you can access the nested entries so not sure what the difference is here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves my problem:

```
{% for block in entry.transformerProductNavigation %}
{% set chosenCategory = block.transformer.last() %}

      {# set a variable – chosenCategory to the 'last' category ensuring any nested categories are accessible   #}
      <a href="{{ chosenCategory.slug }}">{{ chosenCategory.title }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Thanks to this answer: [How to fetch only selected child category?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22962/how-to-fetch-only-selected-child-category).